# An identity for the ratio of two partial Bell polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, sequences-and-series, power-series, integer-sequences

Let $B_{\ell,m}(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_{\ell-m+1})$ denote the Bell polynomials of the second kind (or say, partial Bell polynomials, (exponential) partial Bell partition polynomials). I knew that
the identity
\begin{equation*}\label{0Y0}\tag{o-o}
\frac{B_{\ell+2m+2,\ell}\bigl(1, 0, 1, 0, 9, 0,\dotsc,[(2m-1)!!]^2, 0, [(2m+1)!!]^2\bigr)} {B_{\ell+2m,\ell}\bigl(1, 0, 1, 0, 9, 0,\dotsc,[(2m-3)!!]^2, 0, [(2m-1)!!]^2\bigr)}
=(\ell+2m)^2
\end{equation*}
is valid for $\ell=1,2$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$, but not necessarily valid for $\ell\ge3$ (as the counterexample by Peter Taylor at https://mathoverflow.net/a/456761 shows).

**What is the general expression of the ratio
\begin{equation*}
R(\ell,m)=\frac{B_{\ell+2m+2,\ell}\bigl(1, 0, 1, 0, 9, 0, 225,0,\dotsc,[(2m-1)!!]^2, 0, [(2m+1)!!]^2\bigr)} {B_{\ell+2m,\ell}\bigl(1, 0, 1, 0, 9, 0, 225,0,\dotsc,[(2m-3)!!]^2, 0, [(2m-1)!!]^2\bigr)}
\end{equation*}
for $\ell\ge3$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$?**

Thank you very much for your attention.

References

1. Ch. A. Charalambides, *Enumerative Combinatorics*, CRC Press Series on Discrete Mathematics and its Applications. Chapman & Hall/CRC, Boca Raton, FL, 2002.
2. L. Comtet, *Advanced Combinatorics: The Art of Finite and Infinite Expansions*, Revised and Enlarged Edition, D. Reidel Publishing Co., 1974; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-010-2196-8.
3. Feng Qi, *Taylor's series expansions for real powers of two functions containing squares of inverse cosine function, closed-form formula for specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representations for real powers of Pi*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 710--736; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0157.
4. Feng Qi, *Explicit formulas for partial Bell polynomials, Maclaurin's series expansions of real powers of inverse (hyperbolic) cosine and sine, and series representations of powers of Pi*, Research Square (2021), available online at https://doi.org/10.21203/rs.3.rs-959177/v3.
5. Feng Qi, Gradimir V. Milovanovic, and Dongkyu Lim, *Specific values of partial Bell polynomials and series expansions for real powers of functions and for composite functions*, Filomat **37** (2023), no. 28, 9469--9485; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/FIL2328469Q.
6. Feng Qi and Peter Taylor, *Series expansions for powers of sinc function and closed-form expressions for specific partial Bell polynomials*, Applicable Analysis and Discrete Mathematics **18** (2024), no. 1, in press; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/AADM230902020Q.

Comment: To be clear about which polynomials you're talking about: would $$B_{6,2}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = 6x_5x_1 + 15x_4x_2 + 10x_3^2$$ be an example of what you have in mind? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, you are right.
\begin{equation*}
B_{m,k}(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_{m-k+1})=\sum_{\substack{1\le j\le m-k+1\\ \ell_j\in\{0\}\cup\mathbb{N}\\ \sum_{j=1}^{m-k+1}j\ell_j=m\\
\sum_{j=1}^{m-k+1}\ell_j=k}}\frac{m!}{\prod_{j=1}^{m-k+1}\ell_j!} \prod_{j=1}^{m-k+1}\biggl(\frac{x_j}{j!}\biggr)^{\ell_j}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Sounds like you are counting partial matchings. Writing the sums in terms of combinatorial objects instead of sums with factorials is probably a better way to go. Try colored perfect matchings with $\ell$ colors on a set of of $\ell+2m+2\ell$ elements with $\ell$ distinguished elements forced to end up with different colors inherited from edges.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I am not a combinatorist, so I cannot understand what you sketched.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Are you combinatorially interpreting partial Bell polynomials $B_{m,k}$? My problem is to prove the identity (o-o)! Anyway, thank you very much! But I really need a complete proof of the identity (o-o) in details.

Comment: How far have you tested it numerically? My Sage code may be buggy, but it only seems to hold for $\ell \in \{1, 2\}$, $m > 0$.

Comment: @qifeng618: sorry I was just floating ideas and recommending interpreting the $(2n-1)!!$ as counting perfect matchings of $2n$ elements https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_matching (this requires introducing, e.g., $\ell$ extra fictitious elements) and interpreting the Bell polynomials as counting set partitions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials Since you have squares of $(2n-1)!!$ that means you have not just one but two perfect matchings, say with red and blue edges. A reference which can help for understanding this...

Comment: ...is the article by Krattenthaler https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316596900588

Comment: @PeterTaylor I tested numerically for many $(\ell,m)$, but I neglected those such that the identity (o-o) is not valid. Your findings are true, I made stupid mistakes in the so-called guess. I will modify this question very soon. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: consider $\ell = 3$, $m = 1$. The LHS is $$\frac{B_{7,3}({\color{red} 1}, {\color{green} 0}, {\color{blue} 1}, 0, 9)} {B_{5,3}({\color{red} 1}, {\color{green} 0}, {\color{blue} 1})} =
\frac{105 \cdot {\color{green} 0}^2 \cdot {\color{blue} 1} + 70 \cdot {\color{red} 1} \cdot {\color{blue} 1}^2 + 105 \cdot {\color{red} 1} \cdot {\color{green} 0} \cdot 0 + 21 \cdot {\color{red} 1}^2 \cdot 9} {15 \cdot {\color{red} 1} \cdot {\color{green} 0}^2 + 10 \cdot {\color{red} 1}^2 \cdot {\color{blue} 1}} = \frac{259} {10}$$

Comment: Your numerical test is right, your counterexample is correct. I will modify this question very soon. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For $\ell,m\in\mathbb{N}$, the first three values of the ratio $R(\ell,m)$ are
\begin{align*}
R(1,m)&=(1+2m)^2,\\
R(2,m)&=(2+2m)^2,\\
R(3,m)&=(3+2m)^2\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}}{\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}}.
\end{align*}
This implies that the general expression of the ratio $R(\ell,m)$ shouldn't be of a simple form.